# No puedo agregar el codigo al repo remoto de gitlab con git push origin master?

Tags: gitlab

! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
**texto en negrita** error: falló el push de algunas referencias a 'https://gitlab.com/'

Comment: ese es todo el error que te da?

Comment: si ese es todo el error, obviamente este no es el path completo del repo  'https://gitlab.com/'

Comment: claro, seguro que la rama que queres hacer push existe y que tenes los permisos?

Comment: aqui esta la respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/a/28832644/8747573

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que contactar al dueño del repositorio y averiguar por qué tu push ha sido rechazado.

Git tiene "ganchos" que puedes definir para que se ejecuten en las diferentes etapas de un push/commit u otras operaciones y controlar las acciones que puedan ocurrir sobre el repositorio.

Por ejemplo, podrías estar haciendo push a una rama a la que el dueño del repositorio ha declarado explícitamente una restricción.

Comment: no comprendo la ultimo que mencionas de la restricción

Comment: esto es un comentario, no una respuesta, cuando tengas suficiente reputacion podras realizarlos.

Comment: @DeivisDavidSánchezMestra el dueño de un repositorio puede evitar que personas externas hagan push directamente a una rama. Por ejemplo, podría poner una restricción en master para que sólo se pueda subir cambios a través de Pull Requests o de usuarios de confianza. Es una medida de seguridad.

Comment: @RamiroBarone entiendo que no proporciono una solución como tal. Aún así, tampoco creo que la solución venga de otro lugar que no sea averiguar la razón del rechazo de `pre-receive`. Quiero decir que si esto no es respuesta, no encuentro otra. A lo mejor más contexto sobre el funcionamiento de los git hooks ayudaría?

Comment: El proyecto que intento subir al repo de gitlab anteriormente estaba alojado en githat, ya removi el repo de githat pero no me permite agregar el push al nuevo repo remoto en gitlab

Comment: @DeivisDavidSánchezMestra entiendo que eres el dueño del repositorio, por lo que a lo mejor es un tema de configuración en el repositorio remoto; puede ser tema de permisos de usuarios que puedan hacer push. Podrías actualizar tu pregunta con un paso a paso de las acciones que tomaste (comandos y acciones en githat/gitlab)? También podrías adjuntar capturas de la configuración de los remotos y el output de `git config --list`. Con una idea más clara de la situación será más fácil ayudarte.